# How do I empty a folder using IFileOperation

Tags: c++, windows, file

I have a helper method that looks like this:

```
HRESULT DeleteFolderAndContainedFiles(IShellItem *psiFolder)
{
    IFileOperation *pfo;
    HRESULT hr = CreateAndInitializeFileOperation(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfo));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pfo->DeleteItem(psiFolder, NULL);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pfo->PerformOperations();
        }
        pfo->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}
```

How can I call this method, using `IShellItem` (which I have no experience with)? I want to pass it a path like `C:\data\test` and it should clear everything under the test directory but not delete the `test` directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IShellItem* item = NULL;
SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"C:\\data\\test", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item));
```

Comment: It doesn't help. It would cause `test` folder to be deleted as well.

Comment: @Ajay And that's a wrong thing to do for a function named `DeleteFolderAndContainedFiles` because...?

Comment: Becuase it deletes 'temp' folder also, which is not required by the OP. All files and folders under it should delete, not folder itself.

Comment: @Ajay Well, the specific question the OP asked was "how can I call this method?" This is the question I answered. Perhaps it was a wrong question to ask, if the method doesn't in fact do what the OP really wants to do.

Comment: Should the `IShellItem` be released after use?

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not want to delete the specified folder itself, only its contents, you will have to enumerate the folder's contents and delete them individually.  Try calling `IShellItem::BindToHandler(BHID_EnumItems)` to get an `IEnumShellItems` that represents the contents and pass it to `IFileOperation::DeleteItems()`, rather than passing the `IShellItem` itself to `IFileOperation::DeleteItem()`:

```
hr = psiFolder->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_EnumItems, IID_IEnumShellItems, (void**)&pEnum);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pfo->DeleteItems(pEnum);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pfo->PerformOperations();
    }
}
```