# Delete a file or folder Win32 C++ using IFileOperation

Tags: c++, file, winapi, directory

I was researching how to delete a folder in C++ using Win32 APIs and I came across `SHFileOperation` as well as many remarks on how it is deprecated and how `IFileOperation` is the much more preferred way, but I can't find any complete examples using `IFileOperation`.

Comment: "*I was researching how to delete a folder in C++ using Win32 APIs*" - I'm guessing you didn't find [`RemoveDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-removedirectoryw) and [`DeleteFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefile) during your searches?

Comment: `RemoveDirectory()` requires the folder to be empty and I didn't want to recursively go through the folder and all its subfolders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to put together a function from many sources and here it is:

```cpp
#include <Shobjidl.h> //Required for IFileOperation Interface
#include <shellapi.h> //Required for Flags set in "SetOperationFlags"

BOOL deleteFileOrFolder(LPCWSTR fileOrFolderPath) {
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //Couldn't initialize COM library - clean up and return
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't initialize COM library", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
    //Initialize the file operation
    IFileOperation* fileOperation;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOperation, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&fileOperation));
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //Couldn't CoCreateInstance - clean up and return
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't CoCreateInstance", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
    hr = fileOperation->SetOperationFlags(FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOERRORUI);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //Couldn't add flags - clean up and return
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't add flags", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        fileOperation->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
    IShellItem* fileOrFolderItem = NULL;
    hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(fileOrFolderPath, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&fileOrFolderItem));
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //Couldn't get file into an item - clean up and return (maybe the file doesn't exist?)
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't get file into an item", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        fileOrFolderItem->Release();
        fileOperation->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
    hr = fileOperation->DeleteItem(fileOrFolderItem, NULL); //The second parameter is if you want to keep track of progress
    fileOrFolderItem->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //Failed to mark file/folder item for deletion - clean up and return
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to mark file/folder item for deletion", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        fileOperation->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
    hr = fileOperation->PerformOperations();
    fileOperation->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //failed to carry out delete - return
        MessageBox(NULL, L"failed to carry out delete", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Some of my sources:

- [How do I empty a folder using IFileOperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530002/how-do-i-empty-a-folder-using-ifileoperation)
- [Examples of IFileOperation DeleteItem](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/IFileOperation/DeleteItem/cpp-ifileoperation-deleteitem-method-examples.html)
- [IFileOperation::SetOperationFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-setoperationflags)
- [Copy a file using IFileOperation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/46e5cd7e-1fe7-4245-a201-a3227ceb3c65/copy-a-file-using-ifileoperation)

The parameter `LPCWSTR fileOrFolderPath` should be a complete path to a file or folder to delete, if you wanted to delete multiple files or folders check out:

- [IFileOperationDeleteItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-deleteitems)
- [IShellItemArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitemarray) (For listing out multiple delete entries)

Comment: It is not the responsibility of individual functions to call `CoInitialize/Ex()`/`CoUninitialize()`. They should be called on a per-thread basis instead of a per-function basis.